# error with addwithvalue sql parameter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I've been advised to replace my code with `SqlParameter` to avoid SQL injection as a security issue but with my limited understanding. I tried implementing it but I'm faced with an error:

> Must Declare Scalar Variable

I've tried the other suggestions of other threads about implementing a new parameter for every insertion instead of replacing the value of parameter for every entry.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO EmpInfo(EmpYear, EmpStatus, LName, FName, JobTitle, EmpPay, EmpDoB, EmpSex, EmpAddr, EmpCity, EmpState, EmpZIP, EmpCountry, EmpEAddr, EmpTelNo, EmpMobileNo, EmpDate) " +
               "VALUES('"+EmpYear+"', @EmpStatus, @LName, @FName, @JobTitle, @EmpPay, @EmpDoB, @EmpSex, @EmpAddr, @EmpCity, @EmpState, @EmpZIP, @EmpCountry, @EmpEAddr, @EmpTelNo, @EmpMobileNo, getdate())";
String query2 = "INSERT INTO AccountInfo(LName, FName, EmpTemplate, AccountType, EmpStatus, EmpDate) " +
                "VALUES (@LName, @FName, @EmpTemplate, @AccountType, @EmpStatus, GetDate())";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=RB-DESKTOP;Initial Catalog=TimeDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=bautista7"))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(EmpID) FROM EmpInfo";

    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    rdr.Close();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, cmd.Connection);
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpYear", Value = EmpYear });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpStatus", Value = "Active" });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@LName", Value = regLname_text.Text });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@FName", Value = regFname_text.Text });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@JobTitle", Value = "NULL" });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpPay", Value = PayType_cb.SelectedItem.ToString() });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpDoB", Value = regDob_dtp.Value.Date });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpSex", Value = gender });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpAddr", Value = regAddr_text.Text });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpCity", Value = regCity_text.Text });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpState", Value = regState_text.Text });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpZIP", Value = regZip_text.Text });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpCountry", Value = regCountry_text.Text });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpEAddr", Value = regEmail_text.Text });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpTelNo", Value = regTel_text.Text });
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpMobileNo", Value = regMob_text.Text });

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command.Parameters.Clear();

    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(query2, cmd.Connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", regLname_text.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", regFname_text.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpTemplate", template);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountType", AcctType_cb.SelectedItem.ToString());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpStatus", "Active");

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    command.Parameters.Clear();
```

Comment: what is the errror?  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I'm really sorry but its written on the paragraph. I'm dealt with the exception of "Must Declare Scalar Variable"

Not just with one column, but if not all of them, most.

Comment: But what line cause you that error, and what is the exact error? Also try to test with a simple table first with less fields so you can focus on the error more easy.[**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The ones that I've noticed so far is empyear, jobTitle and EmpPay, could be more since once it throws the exception, it stops. and thats as far as ive gotten.

exception is coming from  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
with the error, "Must Declare Scalar Variable".

Comment: You also add the `@EmpYear` parameter, but you don't actually use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `command` variable twice instead of `command2` after you create `command2`. You get the error because you cleared `command` of all parameters, then add parameters (which do not match the existing query) and then execute `ExecuteNonQuery` which then throws the error.

Change 2nd execution statement / command like so, notice that after the creation of `command2` it is now also used instead of reusing `command`.

```
SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(query2, cmd.Connection);
command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", regLname_text.Text);
command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", regFname_text.Text);
command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpTemplate", template);
command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountType", AcctType_cb.SelectedItem.ToString());
command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpStatus", "Active");
var numberOfRecordsInserted = command2.ExecuteNonQuery();

// value of numberOfRecordsInserted should be 1
```

Also when you are done using a `SqlCommand` you can dispose of it, there is no need to call `SqlCommand.Parameters.Clear()` unless you plan on reusing the exact same `SqlCommand` instance which you are not (at least not in the posted code).

Comment: Thank you so much! you're explanation was really easy to understand! I overlooked a lot of errors. I've been coding this for 3 days straight and i barely had any sleep, thank you! I can rest easy now

Comment: @user3442765 - no problem. If this is your answer please do not forget to mark it as such using the checkbox next to it.

Comment: sorry to bother you once more, I managed to be clear of the errors and ExecuteNonQuery is returning rows affected but when i select * from empinfo in SSMS, the tables are blank.

Comment: I did but it says my reputation is below 15, while it is recorded, it cannot be publicly displayed.

Comment: @user3442765 - this could happen if your connection string points to a different database than you are looking at in SSMS. If you are using LocalDb for example this would be a common mistake. Alternatively if you are using localdb you might be resetting (overwritting the file) the database with every build.

Comment: @user3442765 - I meant the checkbox, not the up arrow. The up arrow is to indicate a useful answer. You can mark many answers as useful. The checkbox is to mark the answer that best helped you, you can only mark one of those in every question.

Comment: oh, i see! checked it!

i see but my connection string reflects my database. i wonder whats wrong.

Comment: @user3442765 - same server and/or same file pointer? You can always add a quick hard coded select as the last statement as a test, if you get results there you know that the code is good and it is a data file issue (looking at the wrong one or overwriting/resetting it with a build).

Comment: I did the hardcode  string query3 = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM EMPINFO ORDER BY EMPID DESC"


 I got an error saying no data is present. i'm so confused now.

Comment: @user3442765 - what is the value that `ExecuteNonQuery` returns? It should be 1, set it equal to some new variable and capture it. If its 0 that means nothing was added. Ill edit my answer to show you.

Comment: @user3442765 - also make sure you do not have multiple tables under different schemas. You should try to use the `dbo` schema so prefix your table names with `dbo.` and do the same in your queries. Example: `INSERT INTO dbo.EmpInfo(....` and `SELECT * FROM dbo.EmpInfo`

Comment: I used something similar with the execute non query, it returned a 1, twice for both inserts. in separate messageboxes.

Comment: I tried adding the dbo.EmpInfo and dbo.AccountInfo, still the same.

Comment: Do you see this increment with every run? `var totalRecords = (new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.EmpInfo", cmd.Connection)).ExecuteNonQuery();`? If not you are overwritting your database. If you are then you are looking at the wrong db in SSMS.

Comment: TotalRecords are returning with a -1. it doesn't increment.

Comment: Then you could be overwriting your database data file with every run. Are you using local db? What is your back end?

Comment: "Data Source=RB-DESKTOP;Initial Catalog=TimeDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;

I'm using a DB from query. through added tables. even if its being overwritten, shouldn't there be like, even a single entry of data?

Comment: @user3442765 - then I would open `Sql Server Profiler` (from SSMS) and see what is happening. You can see all database calls and see if something is droping and creating tables, or droping the database, or cleaning the tabels, etc. You can get an app. name or login name and see the actions happen real time so you know what the culprit is.

Comment: I managed to get them both to work, but my other tables 'EmpID' comes up null. its not replicating the primary key, which si the EmpID from EmpInfo Table

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try simplify your logic first. I found several weird things.

query has `"VALUES('"+EmpYear+"',` I think you want `@EmpYear` because you also have

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpYear", Value = EmpYear });
```

Additionally

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                              //^^^ here you use insert query
cmd.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(EmpID) FROM EmpInfo"; // But here you change it for a SELECT?

// Then you execeute a DataReader but you close it before save the result.
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
rdr.Close();

//Then create the insert command again
SqlCommand commad = new SqlCommand(query, cmd.Connection);

....

// clear command, I guess you want reuse it
command.Parameters.Clear();                

// now create command 2 is OK
SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(query2, cmd.Connection);
                                  // ^^^ second insert query

// but add parameteres to command NOT OK
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", regLname_text.Text);
```

Comment: Sorry my mind has been jumbling things up desperate to fix each problem and sometimes i forget to undo the changes. I put +EmpYear_=+ instead to avoid the declare scalar variable but instead was faced by the same error for a different column. I will try your advice, thank you very much

Comment: sorry to bother you once more, I managed to be clear of the errors and ExecuteNonQuery is returning rows affected but when i select * from empinfo in SSMS, the tables are blank.